# How do i convert the the variable format the way it gets displayed

Tags: sql-server

I have a variable that gives outpur result  as below  08716652211   but i want to diplay it as 871665 ( ignoring the first digit and ignoring the last 4 digits) please help  -- Raman

Comment: What data type is the variable? Have you considered the SUBSTRING function?

Comment: `SUBSTRING('08716652211',2,6)`?

Answer (score -1):

Look into the SUBSTRING() function.